# Callbacks in Firebase and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm going through a Firebase tutorial using angular and it started by making `child_added` requests in a controller, but now we're refactoring and moving those requests to a service -- as we should.

However, there's some syntax being used in the service that I'm not familiar with. Here's my service that's making a `child_added` request to the firebase db:

```
app.service(‘messageService’, function() {
    var messagesRef = new Firebase(FBURL);
    return {
        childAdded: function childAdded(callback) {
            messagesRef.on(‘child_added’, function(data) {
                callback.call(this, {
                    user: data.val().user,
                    text: data.val().text,
                    name: data.name()
                });
            });
        }   
    }
}
```

Then in the controller we're using the service like so:

```
messageService.childAdded(function(addedChild) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.messages.push(addedChild);
    });
});
```

Firstly, I'm confused as to what `callback.call(this, ...` is doing? Secondly, how does that line tie in with `push()` method in the controller?

I would greatly appreciate any explanations. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call()` is just a function in the JavaScript standard library (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Your code:

```
callback.call(this, {
  user: data.val().user,
  text: data.val().text,
  name: data.name()
});
```

Is practically the same thing as saying:

```
callback({
  user: data.val().user,
  text: data.val().text,
  name: data.name()
});
```

`function (addedChild) {...}` is your callback.

Therefore, addedChild, in your code ends up just being:

```
{
  user: data.val().user,
  text: data.val().text,
  name: data.name()
}
```

Where `data` is the DataSnapshot of the added child, `data.val()` being its value and `data.name()` being its key.

The only thing different about using `call()` vs. calling the callback directly is that call allows you to specify the caller, which becomes the `this` object of the callback. (A lot of call* going on in that last sentence).

Comment: Is the `this` keyword referring to the data snapshot?

Comment: No, `this` is referring to the caller of its surrounding function, which is your firebase event callback. I'm not sure what firebase calls its event callbacks with, but after a quick debugging it looks to just be undefined. Edit: undefined, not window object.

Comment: One can pass a context into the Firebase on() method, but since nothing is getting passed in, `this` is indeed undefined here.